# i ajax a file with jquery,and i don't know where does it download to

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "http://images.digu.com/web_res_v1/images/logo.png?t=20091230",
 success: function(msg){ alert( "Data Saved: " +   msg ); } 
});
```

where is the download file.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX request actually only 'download' the requested resource into your browser memory. If you request an image like in your code, the image will be put into browser's cache. So if you set an `img` DOM element's `src` with the same URL, the modern browser will smart enough to use the one in cache.

If you request a part of web page, not an image like your code above, you can insert it directly into DOM element:

```
$.get(URL,
  {},
  function(data){
    $("#container").html(data);
  });
```

Read the [jQuery documentation about AJAX](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) for more example and explaination.

Btw, AJAX request can be only made to the same domain, so make sure that you only request URL in the same domain with your jQuery code. Your code above will only work if the page also in `http://images.digu.com/`.

Second note, use `POST` when you need to send data that will change something in the server side (add, edit, delete). If you just want to request something, use `GET`. Also, if you don't need extra AJAX setting, I recomend you to use `$.post();` and `$.get();` so the code will be more readable and easier to maintain, at least it work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

It is loaded into browser memory, and likely your cache. If you're wanting to save the file, you probably don't want AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't download to a file or anything.  A successful ajax call returns data in a javascript variable. In this case you are saving it into a variable called msg.  Depending on your app, you could insert this data into the webpage (i.e into the DOM).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'd ask for more detail. It seems like you just want to set an image's src property on the fly since I don't see you posting any data. To do that, you can use something like this:

```
$("#my_image").attr("src","http://images.digu.com/web_res_v1/images/logo.png?t=20091230");
```